# Setting rule for a new collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The 2nd and 3rd rule in the below code work as expected. I'm trying to specify the access conditions for the `mailingList` collection to allow anyone to write. However, this is always blocking.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    match /malingList/{doc} {
        allow write: if true; 
    }
    match /metadata/{doc} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null; 
    }
    match /taken/{doc}{
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read,write: if
          request.auth.uid == doc;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "this is always blocking" => In which context? Can you share the code used to write to this collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a typo:

Rules =>  `match /malingList/{doc} {}`  without `i` between `a` and `l`

but you want to write to the `mailingList` collection.

Comment: wow.. I'm an idiot. Thanks and sorry for the trouble